# How to Return list of anyObjects with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How do I return objects retrieved from **Parse**? I'm having problem returning either a list of `PFObject` or `AnyObject`. Also tried not to return a list and just assign a `self.array` within the method.

I retrieve objects using a query in my getSteps() method:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Intervaller")
query.whereKey("namn", equalTo:"elit")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

I can then use the list of objects within the same method without a problem by casting to `PFObject`:

```
if let list = objects as? [PFObject] {   
    for object in list {
        let steps = object["steps"] as! Int
        var myString = String(steps)
         println(myString)
    }
}
```

To use the objects in other methods should I return a list of `PFObject` or `AnyObject`? I have tried both without success, i.e. no objects are assigned to my new list.

If I try `self.steps = objects!` to assign the list to my `var steps = [AnyObject]()` I'm not sure if any objects are being assigned to my new list. I do not get any values out in the for loop using this code

```
self.getSteps() //calling the method where the Parse query is run and self.steps are assigned to objects!  

if let list = self.steps as? [PFObject] {
    for object in list {
        let steps = object["steps"] as! Int
        var myString = String(steps)
        println(myString)
    }

}
```

Whats the best approach and how do I cast and return/assign correctly?

Comment: In your block, using `self.steps = objects` should be fine, can you be more clear what the problem is that you are seeing? What do yo mean by 'no success'?

Comment: The problem is that my self.list seems to be empty or does not atleast give me any values when I then cast to PFObject and try to retrieve steps. I added another code snippet from when I try to use the list again after calling the getSteps() method wich fetches the objects from parse. Is the self.steps= objects the way to go? I'm more use to returning lists from when I used java.

Comment: I think `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is an asynchronous method and so the completion block will not have been called when your `self.getSteps()` call returns. Your `getSteps` method cannot return the list due to its not being synchronous.

Comment: Just posted an answer with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func getSteps() {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Intervaller")
    query.whereKey("namn", equalTo:"elit")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        self.steps = objects as? [PFObject]
        // Only at this point, which will be sometime after the getSteps method has returned, will self.steps be valid
    }
    // At this point in the code the completion handler has not been called so we cannot return the list.
}
```

For example:

```
self.getSteps() //calling the method where the Parse query is runned and (self.steps is not assigned before this method returns.)
// Here self.steps is not valid, since the parse query is running in the background and the completion block will not have been executed yet.
// The following code would be best off being included in the completion handler of the parse query.
if let list = self.steps as? [PFObject] {
    for object in list {
        let steps = object["steps"] as! Int
        var myString = String(steps)
        println(myString)
    }
}
```

So you could either include the code that needs self.steps in the completion handler in the getSteps() method. Or you can make the getSteps method asynchronous by giving it a completion block that you call from the queries completion block:

```
func getSteps(completion: (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Intervaller")
    query.whereKey("namn", equalTo:"elit")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        self.steps = objects as? [PFObject]
        // Call the getSteps method's completion handler
        completion(objects: objects, error: error)
    }
}
```

Then you can call:

```
self.getSteps() { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let list = self.steps as? [PFObject] {
        for object in list {
            let steps = object["steps"] as! Int
            var myString = String(steps)
            println(myString)
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if any of this needs clarifying.

Comment: I had to do a minor change in your suggestion: self.steps = (objects as? [PFObject])! otherwise it was a great answer, Thank you very much!!